# Footer is not fixed

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar

I have this code: http://codepen.io/mbaran/pen/PGxJLw

When i add li tag to the list "myUL", scrollbar is enable but the P is not fixed bottom.

```
<p id="sum">stackoverflow</p>
```

Thank you!

Comment: try `position:fixed` `<p id="sum" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;">stackoverflow</p>`

Comment: its not help...

Comment: Are you fixed with bottom of menu or the page footer?